# Problems calling a recursive function on a multi-dimensional nested array

Tags: ruby, recursion, multidimensional-array, saas

I am trying to split the sub-arrays if there are more than 8. I have tried calling the rps_tournament_winner function on players if it has a flattened length longer than 16 but I get a "stack too deep error".

Do I have to work on the players variable or tournament? I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction; not a complete solution.

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  return rps_game_winner(tournament) if tournament.flatten.length == 4
  players = tournament.flatten(2)  

  while players.length > 1
    players = players.each_slice(2).map { |x| rps_game_winner(x) }
  end

  players[0]
end
```

Comment: Looks like you're recursively calling the function without modifying the argument before doing so.  This would cause an infinite loop.  You need to reduce the argument `tournament` in some way first.

Comment: So if I check for length and if it is over a certain length could I split it into 2 smaller arrays and call the tournament function on each?

Comment: Got it sorted, thanks. Was able to tweak an If statement and got it running perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should be able to delete your question yourself, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: ah, but if I delete it, I lose some of the few rep points I have, no? :)

Comment: There is no answer for me to accept and I cannot close the question myself (not enough rep).

Comment: You can add your own answer and accept that. It may help someone in the future and you don't lose reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using recursion

```
class WrongNumberOfPlayersError < StandardError ; end
class NoSuchStrategyError < StandardError ; end

def rps_game_winner(game)
  raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError unless game.length == 2
  if game[0][0].is_a?(Array) then
    winner1 = rps_game_winner(game[0])
    winner2 = rps_game_winner(game[1])
    game = [winner1, winner2]
  end
  raise NoSuchStrategyError unless /^(P|R|S){2}$/ =~ game[0][1] + game[1][1]
  case game[0][1]
    when "R"
      if game[1][1] == "P" then
        game[1]
      else
        game[0]
      end
    when "P"
      if game[1][1] == "S" then
        game[1]
      else 
        game[0]
      end
    when "S"
      if game[1][1] == "R" then
        game[1]
      else
        game[0]
      end
  end
end

def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  rps_game_winner(tournament)
end
```

Comment: Cool =) I love how there are always multiple ways to solve programming problems (I am fairly new to programming at all)

Answer (score 6):

This is the shortest I was able to come up with (with recursion)

```
def rps_tournament_winner(games)
   if games.flatten.length > 4
     rps_game_winner([rps_tournament_winner(games[0]), rps_tournament_winner(games[1])])
   else
     rps_game_winner(games)
   end
end
```

Comment: I think recursion was the way to go, nice solution =D

Comment: Yeah, when I realized `flatten` could be used, it became kind of obvious and it hit me :). Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

This is also an elegant solution w/o flattening the array:

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
    if tournament[0][0].is_a?(Array)
        tournament =[rps_tournament_winner(tournament[0]), rps_tournament_winner(tournament[1])]
    end
    rps_game_winner(tournament)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only answering this to close the question, hopefully my answer will help some one else =D**

After staring at it for about three hours, my mind actually stopped napping and i came up with this:

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  return rps_game_winner(tournament) if tournament.flatten.length == 4
  if tournament.flatten.length == 16
    players = tournament.flatten(2)
  else
    players = tournament.flatten(4)  
  end

  while players.length > 1
    players = players.each_slice(2).map { |x| rps_game_winner(x) }
  end

players[0]
end
```

The *if* statement allows me to check that if a tournament of 8 or more players (the testing was only for 8, 16 and 32 players so I doubt this would work for larger sets) My problem before was that I would only *flatten(2)* which for the larger tournament would not work.